# UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, iOS8 and secure text entry

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, swift2

I have a form with a "secure text entry" and I want to scroll up my view when the keyboard is opening.

I'm listening to the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` but when the focus is on the password field, this notification is send again and my view scroll up one more time.

Is there a way to avoid this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution: Use a `UITableView`.

Second solution: Don't scroll blindly when ever the keyboard shows. Check the frame of the view or the content offset before you scroll the view. Makes the feature much more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend not moving the offset of the UIScrollView tbh. Better to change the contentInset like so:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size.height {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardHeight, 0.0)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardHeight = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().size.height {
            scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        }
    }
}
```

You might still want to fiddle around with the contentInstent height when the keyboard appears. When you do this though, it won't move the view, instead just create the space required for the keyboard and it feels less jarring for the user.